# How to override LinearGradientBrush defined in data template in another xaml file without copying the whole template again

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, themes, basedon

In my WPF application, I have some purchased grid theme applied on all over app, a CR is required to be able to modify this theme per module/screen, the modification scope will be brushes, colors & styles "using BasedOn" ... So if i have brushes defined/used internally in some template how to override it in the local module xaml without copying the whole template again and regarding brushes and colors is it enough to redefine them again with the same key in the local xaml

Here's the Control template with brushes i want to modify:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="tableViewColumnManagerRowTemplate"
                TargetType="xcdg:ColumnManagerRow">

  <ControlTemplate.Resources>
     <xcdg:ThicknessConverter x:Key="thicknessConverter"
                              InverseValue="True"/>
  </ControlTemplate.Resources>

  <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- HierarchicalGroupLevelIndicatorPane -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <!-- GroupLevelIndicatorPane -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

        <!-- CellsHost panel -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <!-- GroupLevelIndicatorPane is a placeholder for individual GroupLevelIndicator elements that are added
                   whenever this Row is part of a group. -->
     <xcdg:HierarchicalGroupLevelIndicatorPane Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Column="0" />
     <xcdg:GroupLevelIndicatorPane x:Name="groupLevelIndicatorPane"
                                   Grid.Column="1" />


     <Grid Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
           Grid.Column="1"
           xcdg:TableView.CanScrollHorizontally="False">

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="17*" />

           <RowDefinition Height="8*" />

           <RowDefinition Height="10*" />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border x:Name="Border1"
                Background="#121212"
                Grid.RowSpan="4"/>

        <!--Bottom Gradient-->
        <Border x:Name="grpManborderBottomGradient"
                Grid.Row="2">
           <Border.Background>

              <LinearGradientBrush
                 StartPoint="0.125,1"
                 EndPoint="0.125,0.0142">

                 <GradientStop Color="#445282" // This to be overridden
                               Offset="0" />

                 <GradientStop Color="#29314D"// This to be overridden
                               Offset="0.53" />

                 <GradientStop Color="#12131D"// This to be overridden
                               Offset="0.95" />

              </LinearGradientBrush>

           </Border.Background>
        </Border>

        <!--Top Gradient-->
        <Border x:Name="topGradientBorder"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Opacity="0.8"
                Grid.Row="0">
           <Border.Background>

              <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,1"
                                   EndPoint="0.5,0">

                 <GradientStop Color="#393F4D" // This to be overridden
                               Offset="0" />

                 <GradientStop Color="#4A5367" // This to be overridden
                               Offset="0.33" />

                 <GradientStop Color="#626C88" // This to be overridden
                               Offset="1" />

                 <GradientStop Color="#FF5F6A87"// This to be overridden
                               Offset="0.988" />

              </LinearGradientBrush>

           </Border.Background>
        </Border>

        <!--internal border, needs to be last to be over other gradients-->
        <Border x:Name="Border2"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="#9CA3B5"
                Margin="0,0,0,0"
                Grid.RowSpan="3"/>

     </Grid>
     -->Template to be continued...
```